# Data split over 2 rows for each row entry - read in with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with a dataset where each 'entry' is split over many rows which are different sizes, 
i.e.

```
 yyyymmdd hhmmss     lat     lon   name       nprt depth ubas  udir cabs  cdir
        hs     tp     lp       theta     sp      wf
 20140701 000000 -76.500 208.000  'grid_point'  1  332.2  2.8 201.9 0.00   0.0
  0    0.10    1.48    3.40   183.19    30.16   0.89
  1    0.10    1.48    3.40   183.21    29.66   0.90
 20140701 000000 -74.500 251.000  'grid_point'  1    1.0  8.4 159.7 0.00   0.0
  0    0.63    4.24   28.02   105.05    32.71   0.85
  1    0.60    4.21   27.68   110.42    27.04   0.95
  2    0.20    5.78   52.18    43.73    17.98   0.01
  3    0.06    6.55   66.86   176.86    11.04   0.10
 20140701 000000 -74.500 258.000  'grid_point'  0    1.0  7.7 137.0 0.00   0.0
  0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00
```

I'm only interested in the rows that begin with a date so the rest can be discarded. However, the number of additional rows varies throughout the data set (see code snippet for an example).

Ideally, I'd like to use pandas read_csv but I'm open to suggestions if that's not possible/there are easier ways.

So my question is how do you read data into a dataframe where the row begins with a date?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first, then try cast first and second column [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` - it add `NaT` where are not `dates`. So last need filter rows with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and mask created by [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""yyyymmdd hhmmss     lat     lon   name       nprt depth ubas  udir cabs  cdir
        hs     tp     lp       theta     sp      wf
 20140701 000000 -76.500 208.000  'grid_point'  1  332.2  2.8 201.9 0.00   0.0
  0    0.10    1.48    3.40   183.19    30.16   0.89
  1    0.10    1.48    3.40   183.21    29.66   0.90
 20140701 000000 -74.500 251.000  'grid_point'  1    1.0  8.4 159.7 0.00   0.0
  0    0.63    4.24   28.02   105.05    32.71   0.85
  1    0.60    4.21   27.68   110.42    27.04   0.95
  2    0.20    5.78   52.18    43.73    17.98   0.01
  3    0.06    6.55   66.86   176.86    11.04   0.10
 20140701 000000 -74.500 258.000  'grid_point'  0    1.0  7.7 137.0 0.00   0.0
  0    0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00   0.00"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True)
```

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0] + df.iloc[:,1], errors='coerce', format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
0           NaT
1    2014-07-01
2           NaT
3           NaT
4    2014-07-01
5           NaT
6           NaT
7           NaT
8           NaT
9    2014-07-01
10          NaT
dtype: datetime64[ns]

mask = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0] + 
                      df.iloc[:,1], errors='coerce', format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
         .notnull()
print (mask)
    print (mask)
0     False
1      True
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9      True
10    False
dtype: bool
```

```
print (df[mask])

   yyyymmdd  hhmmss      lat      lon          name nprt  depth  ubas   udir  \
1  20140701  000000  -76.500  208.000  'grid_point'    1  332.2   2.8  201.9   
4  20140701  000000  -74.500  251.000  'grid_point'    1    1.0   8.4  159.7   
9  20140701  000000  -74.500  258.000  'grid_point'    0    1.0   7.7  137.0   

   cabs  cdir  
1   0.0   0.0  
4   0.0   0.0
```